# How to migrate from IBM Websphere to Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, migration, websphere

I want to migrate the existing IBM Websphere application server to equivalent Tomcat application server?

Second, how to configure this migrated Tomcat application server with IBM HTTP Server (ihs)?

To brief the current system, We are running simple web application with Servlets/JSP's for file uploading/downloading

Please let me know for any clarifications.

Comment: You will have lots of issues while migrating to Tomcat, as it is just a web container not JEE server. I'd suggest to try WebSphere Liberty or Open Liberty, as it is as lightweight as Tomcat, but provides full Java EE stack.

Comment: If you move to Tomcat, you should pick a different webserver/proxy server than IHS, since IHS isn't supported separately from the products it is bundled with and isn't maintained with tomcat in mind.

Comment: you mean, we can not use Tomcat with IHS? If yes, then can I use Apache as a web server?

Comment: @SudhakarReddy , are you done with this migration , can you please list down the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to migrate with keeping the same level of J2EE, or it could break some things (deprecated methods, new behaviours,..)

- check Java versions on both sides, probably use the same versions even they are coming from different companies (IBM, Oracle)
- check the J2EE version supported by IBM Websphere, [choose Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) accordingly
- once you have your Java and Tomcat installed, copy your application to Tomcat's webapps directory (whatever it is : a war file or a directory)
- you might have some libraries to copy in lib directory (JDBC, javamail,..) but you didn't talk about
- check Tomcat's logs, particularly catalina.out to see the deployment's result

There is no IHS for Tomcat, you will edit some files. These files should be considered :

- conf/server.xml where you define the listening port (8080 on the default's connector), keep it by default but probably you will need to set [attributes](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes) for your uploading
- bin/setenv.sh is the place where to declare the JVM options (JAVA_HOME, memory settings such as the heap space, the log verbosity like PrintGCDetails and others)

Depending on your application, the context can be configured in different ways.

For the beginning, just follow the items from the first list and see if it starts. If it doesn't start, check the logs and probably work around the setenv file to adjust memory.

Comment: I understand that, I can not use IHS as a web server for tomcat application server. Shall I use the Apache as a web server, which is installed in one linux box, and tomcat application server can be installed in another linux box? All I want is, all the HTTP requests should go through with web server and delegate the servlet/JSP requests to Tomcat app server. Pls confirm. Thx

Comment: I confirm that @SudhakarReddy