# Migrating from tomcat to websphere

Tags: java, tomcat, web, migration, websphere

At the moment, I'm developing a java web application locally(localhost) on Windows, using Tomcat 8.5 .

Unofortunately, I have no developing enviroment, so I have to do everything locally and then deploy to production via .WAR .

> The issue is that the production application server (Linux RedHat) is running on websphere, if I generate the .WAR on tomcat, Will I have any problems to run it on WebSphere? **Should I change anything in my code or web xml?**

My system does nothing fancy, no hibernate, no spring, just a very classic mvc web application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are looking for the opposite of [Websphere to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286812/7748072). I believe my answer could help, have a look.

Comment: @EugèneAdell hello Eugene, thanks for the reply. What do you mean? I'm right now using tomcat, but i'll begin to use websphere in the production server. Nevertheless, your answer does help me! I just have one doubt, what's the equivalente of WebApps folder on websphere? Thank you

Comment: I mean the philosophy from migrating to one to another is similar (Java versions, libraries, JVM tuning for memory and maybe a couple of environment properties). I haven't touched a Websphere for years, sorry, I think you will deploy your war through the admin interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you shouldn't have to make any changes, but there are some differences between the two environments that could cause issues.

IBM provides a tool that will analyze your application and suggest changes that may need to be made. You can find more information here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mw-1701-was-migration/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Brent! My lack of experience is at fault here, thanks fore replying.